# Origine di 'in soldoni'

Tags: phrase-origin

L'espressione **in soldoni** significa  *in modo approssimativo ma molto semplice e chiaro*.

> - **Dire in soldoni**; ossia dire in maniera chiara e semplice.
> - **Metterla in soldoni**; mettere la questione in maniera approssimativa ma chiara.

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20in%20soldoni&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20soldoni%3B%2Cc0) l'espressione sembra essere in uso dall'inizio del '900 e come risulta dal l'estratto che segue, sembra avere origini dialettali venete:

> - Il fatto, gittato proprio [in soldoni](https://books.google.it/books?id=PDkyAQAAMAAJ&q=%22in%20soldoni%22&dq=%22in%20soldoni%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=q0_mVOr3I6bNygO_-oHwDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBTgK), come dicono i veneti è che le Società traevano un cospicuo, un enorme vantaggio dal loro esercizio. Ne lavoravano, certo, per i begli occhi del Re di Prussia. Ora è naturale che il vantaggio che traevano le ...(Atti del Parlamento italiano: Discussioni, Volume 14, 1907).

Qual è l'origine di questo modo di dire?

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soldone/

Comment: @egreg - ci sono riferimenti all'origine dell'espressione nel link?

Comment: No, per questo ho solo scritto un commento.

Comment: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/soldo.shtml fa riferimento al fatto che "in soldoni" faccia riferimento alle dimensioni del soldone, una moneta circolata in antichità che era più grande ma con minore valore del metallo

Comment: @JoeTaras - sì, avevo letto questo commento, ma è molto generico e senza alcun riferimento ad un contesto storico o geografico. Mi sembra più una supposizione che altro. Grazie per il link.

Comment: Se dovessi indovinare, direi che si riferisca al fatto di contare solo le denominazioni di denaro "grosse", tralasciando i valori minori, ovvero trascurando "i centesimini" dell'argomento e concentrandosi sull'ordine di grandezza primario

Comment: @Josh61 il soldone come moneta ti dà proprio un riferimento geografico e storico. Lo puoi piazzare al periodo in cui l'argento sali' di valore (metà del sec. XVI circa) forzando le dimensioni e peso del soldo che fu chiamato soldino ed il soldo in rame che, visto il materiale più povero era più grande per mantenere il peso e valore, fu chiamato soldone. Geograficamente sembra riferirsi più all'area del Veneto. (Ref. enciclopedia Treccani) L'origine dell'espressione la puoi derivare da questo e non può, dopotutto, essere troppo lontana dal periodo e luogo di emissione del tipo di moneta.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren - grazie per il commento. Di dove sei?

Comment: Per il nick? haha... Italiano, da vicino Venezia, ora pendolare Italia-Canada

Comment: se lo deve essere inventato qualcuno che non gli garbava l'espressione: > in parole povere.

Comment: Il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000317.jpg) conferma che l'espressione si è cominciata a usare all'inizio del Novecento: la prima attestazione che dà è del 1907.

Answer (score 2):

**Qual è il significato di questo modo di dire?**

> La locuzione **in soldoni** siginifica in breve, in concreto, in parole povere
>   (attraverso un significato intermedio di «in moneta valida, in denaro
>   contante e sonante, senza cioè perdersi in chiacchiere»). (Ref. [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soldone)).  
>   Nel modo più realistico, o nel modo più schietto, o pratico, o concreto. Anche nel modo più chiaro, comprensibile, semplice e sintetico, detto di una conclusione, un discorso, un ragionamento e simili.

**Qual è l'origine di questo modo di dire?**

Questa parola viene usata perché allude alle dimensioni del soldone, ossia del soldo coniato in rame o in lega così chiamato per le sue proporzioni maggiori del normale, dovute al minor valore del metallo impiegato rispetto all'argento.

Come ha già scritto @Erik vanDoren

> Il soldone come moneta ti dà proprio un riferimento geografico e
>   storico. Lo puoi piazzare al periodo in cui l'argento salì di valore
>   (metà del sec. XVI circa) forzando le dimensioni e peso del soldo che
>   fu chiamato soldino ed il soldo in rame che, visto il materiale più
>   povero era più grande per mantenere il peso e valore, fu chiamato
>   soldone. Geograficamente sembra riferirsi più all'area del Veneto.
>   (Ref. [enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/soldo-soldino-soldone_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/)). L'origine dell'espressione la puoi
>   derivare da questo e non può, dopotutto, essere troppo lontana dal
>   periodo e luogo di emissione del tipo di moneta.

Comment: Tuttavia, come spiegato nella domanda, e come conferma il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000317.jpg), che dà una prima attestazione del 1907, sembra che questa espressione si sia cominciata a usare all'inizio del Novecento.